# Send pdf/jpg file in http post request - server error

Tags: vb6

I want to send Image or pdf document in post request, the URL is working fine, but in visual basic I used the below code to send the document using url but It gives me failure response server error .
I have checked URL, it has no issue, but when I tried to implement in vb, in response I get the 500  server error

```
Dim strFile As String  
Dim uploadDocUrl As String
Dim baBuffer() As Byte
Dim sPostData As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFileName As String   

strFile = "C://Users/Avinashi/Desktop/1.pdf"
uploadDocUrl = "http://api.tally.messaging.bizbrain.in/api/v1/uploadFile"
strFileName = "1.pdf"
nFile = FreeFile

Open strFile For Binary Access Read As nFile
If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
Get nFile, , baBuffer
sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
End If
Close nFile

sPostData = "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
"Content-Disposition: form-data;name=""1.pdf""; filename=""" & Mid$(strFile, InStrRev(strFile, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
"Content-Type:multipart/form-data" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
sPostData & vbCrLf & _
"--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"

 With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
.Open "POST", uploadDocUrl, bAsync
.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
.SetRequestHeader "token", "78bea912b4a5c497b85926bb471fab04"
.Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)
MsgBox (.responseText)
End With

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
    pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbUnicode)
End Function
```

Comment: Is it correct to use forward slashes / in the file path, instead of backslashes \  ?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs ,  I tried with the both slashes, but its not creating any issue..so its fine.

Comment: I was able to run this code without errors.  I know this doesn't help your situation, but at least the syntax appears to be correct.

Comment: @Brain M Stafford thanks for checking, but please tell me that in VB.Net if I want to send the file in post request then there is  restRequest.AddFile("file",FilePath) method is available, what should be the replacement for this code for the same process to achieve it in VB6 ? may be this will make my day.

Comment: "the URL is working fine" -- here is your problem. Show us the code that receives the file. You cannot just "upload" to an URL, there must be a server-side code that will accept this `multipart/form-data` you are sending to it. In the [original blog post of mine this code was hoisted from](https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/) there is a sample PHP code for the accepting server-side part. Show us what you are using here. Is it PHP? Is it VB.Net?

Comment: @wqw I don't have the server side code access, but I an assure you that its working, I am posting the API call response that I made externally for the same URL 

    {
     "flag": true,
     "message": "File Upload SuccessFully",   "data":"http://api.tally.messaging.bizbrain.in/uploadAttachment/715aca626c0ed8a1bae0721f4515f71c.PDF"
    }

Comment: There a multiple ways to upload a file. The server-side code and the uploading client-side code has to agree on numerous things. You cannot just slap any `mutlipart/form-data` code to any server-side code and expect things to miraculously work. This is like using the above code to upload to an FTP server or IRC server -- it's not going to fly w/o carefully adjusting all the moving parts. What filename is the server-side code expecting? What form element name? Is it `multipart/form-data` the content type expect to begin with or JSON in POST body or different encoding?